# What's the name of the function that helps localise part of body without looking?

Tags: neurology, neuroscience

What function in the brain allows it to locate body parts in space without looking?

How is it possible to eat without looking? Why are some people able to catch food that has been thrown at them? Are these functions linked? If not what are these functions? Can someone enumerate them?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "[proprioception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprioception)".

Briefly, it works because you have sensors in your own muscles and joints that can sense their stretch and position.